# Forking a repository into an existing reposiroty

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a `project repository` which I want to align with another repository, let's call it `template-repository`.
Normally we fork from the `template-repository` and then start working.

But this  project repository was created as a standalone, without being forked from `template-repository`.

Can I align the `project repository` with the `template-repository`?
Adding it as one of it's forked repositories, without creating a new `project repository`?

Thanks.

Comment: Either delete and re-create it or pull from the template and push to the repository that should be the fork.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `template-repository` as a remote to your current existing project :

```
# if you intend to use 'template-repository' as the default remote named
# 'origin', just use 'origin' instead of 'template' below
git add remote template url/to/template-reporistory

git fetch template
```

You can now do whatever you want in your local repo :

- create a branch from `template/master`, move your work there, and commit,
- rebase your current branch on top of `template/master`
- cherry-pick commits from `template/master`
- ...